# Парсер курл прокси

Tags: curl

Хочу спарсить сайт с помощью курла и прокси.
 Вот код:

```
function curl($url)

   {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, " Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0
                .2564.109 Safari/537.36");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '94.181.34.64:8080');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $output;
    }
     $auth = curl($link);

            $parser = phpQuery::newDocument($auth);
        echo $parser;
```

Но в результате пустой екран. Подскажите где ошибка. Курлом пользовался всегда,но с прокси и такими проблемами столкнулся впервые.2) Если все делать без прокси,то сайт пропускает 1-2 раза,потом блочит ip. И даже в позитивном случае автоматически происхолит редирект на сам сайт, то есть выгрузки контента не происходит.Как это исправить? Спасибо